# Sort and echo data from array by email domain

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, html-table

I currently have an array which I need to sort by email domain to post the data I have into a table.
Here is the array I currently have (a shortened example) :

```
Array
(
[0] => wlrb@yahoo.com:7:8.35
[1] => hcda@able.com:4:5.59
[2] => kkyhid@hotmail.com:3:9.29
[3] => dxrjmowf@able.com:4:6.67
[4] => ybldb@hotmail.com:8:22.84
[5] => rcbyn@widgets.com:7:14.80
[6] => ggxxpkl@able.com:6:8.36
[7] => lnmpapq@hotmail.com:5:18.67
[8] => opkmc@widgets.com:5:22.88
[9] => wnkue@able.com:10:18.68
[10] => mgbbuqc@bodge.com:2:19.67
[11] => vswmdkqtb@bodge.com:5:21.89
```

and here is the code I am using currently  to do this

```
<?php
    $filename = "orderdata.txt";
   // Open the file
 $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r'); 

 // Add each line to an array
 if ($fp) {
 $array = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));
 }
 function pr($data)
 {
      print "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
      print "</pre>";
 }
 pr($array);
    ?>
```

I would like to post the data into a table in this format(cant use a database):

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                     able.com                  |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
| andy@able.com |         1        |      20.30 |
| ed@able.com   |         4        |       5.05 |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
|                     bodge.com                 |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
| foo@bodge.com |         3        |     132.20 |
+---------------+------------------+------------+
```

The second column is order amount and the last column is price.

Could anyone help me in my quest?

Comment: you need to use file('orderdata.txt'); instead of what you do the nyou need explode data by ':' to get parts of the string. Then you need regex to get domain from mail or in simpler version explode by '@' the mail and you need to sort array with array_multisort()

Comment: @Robert could you explain this further please? I'm having a really hard time with this problem :(

Comment: I'll try to write you some code

Comment: @Robert Apparently I need to use an associative array to deliver the data, my head is hurting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = "orderdata.txt";
$details =  file($filename);
$emails = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($details);$i++) {
    $curr = explode(":", $details[$i]);
    $curr[0] = explode("@", $curr[0]);
    $emails[$curr[0][1]][] = array($curr[0][0], $curr[1], $curr[2]);
}

ksort($emails);
print "<table border=1 width=500>";

foreach($emails as $k => $v) {
    print "<tr><td colspan='3' align=center>".$k."</td></tr>";
    foreach($v as $value) {
        print "<tr><td>".$value[0]."</td><td>".$value[1]."</td><td>".$value[2]."</td></tr>";
    }
}
print "</table>";
```

This it?

Comment: Kind of yeah, but how do I draw the data into the array from the external file 'orderdata.txt'? I also need to put the domains in ascending alphabetical order but getting them printing proper is more important at the moment.

EDIT: I've got the array printing from the .txt file now, dumb moment sorry. I just need to get the domains printing in ascending order.

Comment: EDIT: I've got the array printing from the .txt file now, dumb moment sorry. I just need to get the domains printing in ascending order.

Comment: Its not printing the code properly here, i'll add as a comment.

Comment: Gone back a step now lol, `sort($emails);` has replaced the 'yahoo.com' etc with numbers..

Comment: EDIT: fixed the sort.

Comment: Aha! Getting there, thank you. This line:
``$emails[$curr[0][1]][] = array($curr[0][0], $curr[1],      $curr[2]);``

Is still giving me problems...
**Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php on line 22**

Comment: Mind sending me the example file as well as your edits so I can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: Here it is on drop box
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/avnus7jh0ub5rbj/AADREeP688kDdJDB8M6cr_z7a?dl=0

Comment: [Test Code Page](http://jdl-enterprises.co.uk/test.php) seems to work fine... weird...

Comment: Thats odd, maybe its just because I'm using a more restrictive version of PHP or something.. I don't know. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "orderdata.txt";
// Open the file as array
$lines =  file($filename);
$newArray = array();

foreach($lines as $line)
{
  $parts = explode(":", $line);
  $email = explode("@", $parts[0]);

  $newArray[] = array(
          'email' => $parts[0],
          'emailDomain' => $email[1],
          'order' => $parts[1],
          'price' => $parts[2]
  );
}

print_r($newArray);
```

The code will extract the parts you want and put it in new array. You will still need to sort it with `array_multisort()` or any other way. Parts can be also extracted using preg_match but explode is simplier in this case.

Comment: Returns a couple of errors....

`Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php on line 26

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php on line 27

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\index.php on line 28`

So then my array looks like this...





`Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => [emailDomain] => [order] => [price] => ) [1] => Array ( [email] => aciohord@able.com [emailDomain] => able.com [order] => 1 [price] => 21.61 ) [2] => Array ( [email] => afspqpq@bodge.com [emailDomain] => bodge.com [order] => 3 [price] => 13.22 ) `

Comment: I don't know what you do wrong but I put the code into fiddle and it works http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e22defcdf5757b81789240147b78e9d6b337faa

the errors you have are because you have your data in different format that you provided in question. They need to be in rows every row seprarated by newline